# Resetting Position Relative to Rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Currently I have the following two issues:

- The first issue being that when I reset my camera position I have to also reset my camera rotation. This is due to the fact that my camera
  offset is set to a position slightly off of my player on the z and y
  axis and obviously those values should change depending on my cameras
  rotation although I am unsure how to figure out what those values
  should be.
- My second issue is that my rotation uses a raycast to find the middle of
  the screen and determine its rotation origin although it seems to be
  slightly off the middle of the screen as when it rotates the rotation
  origin moves as well, if it is indeed in the middle of the screen
  shouldn't it be completely still? Also is there a better and less
  expensive way of achieving my desired rotation?

Relevant piece of code:

```
void RotateCamera()
{
    //Find midle of screen
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2, 0));
    RaycastHit hitInfo;

    //Checks if ray hit something
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo))
    {
        //Rotate left and right
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            transform.RotateAround(hitInfo.point, -Vector3.up, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            transform.RotateAround(hitInfo.point, Vector3.up, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }

    //Draws Raycast
    Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * 100, Color.yellow);
}

void ResetCameraPosition()
{
    //Reset and lock camera position
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
    transform.position = player.transform.position + cameraOffset;

}
```

[Image displaying what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUTvC.jpg)

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you actually want the camera to do? I think I get that you want to rotate around a point and on demand reset to the players current facing but please confirm.

Comment: Yeah, and a screenshot or a drawing (even programmer art) would help a lot

Comment: @Absinthe Yes, sorry that is basically it I want to rotate the camera around the very middle of the screen so basically it rotates around what ever it is looking at perfectly, the code i have currently does an okay job of that but its focus point slightly moves when rotating and it seems like an expensive way of calculating it. And as for the reset rotation part I wish to reset my camera to the way that it is already rotated although have it positioned in a way that would see my character. Hope this clears it up. Thanks!

Comment: @Mark Thanks, Ill be sure to add that!

Comment: There's a good example of using Mathf.SmoothDampAngle to achieve this kind of orbit cam here https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.SmoothDampAngle.html. I don't think you need the raycast at all, just set a target for the camera e.g. the player's transform.

Comment: @Absinthe Thanks for the reply, although what would the target be as I always want it to rotate around the middle of the screen no matter where the camera is position and that wont always be the players position, I spose I could make an invisible game object that always moves with the camera although I feel as though there is probably a better way. Also that doesn't solve my resetting camera issue.

Comment: Ok, I get what you mean. I've posted an answer that should help.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html) to create a 'target' in the middle of the screen around which to pivot. Remove all the raycasting stuff as you don't need it and replace the relevant bits with:

```
float rotationSpeed = 45; // or whatever speed
float distance = 5f; // or whatever radius for the orbit
Vector3 target = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2, distance));

if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
{
    transform.RotateAround(target , -Vector3.up, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
{
    transform.RotateAround(target , Vector3.up, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Comment: Issue with that code is I don't know my distance hence the raycast, also it doesn't answer the first and main part of my question.